# Spin interaction of Virtual Phonon's forming Cooper Pairs

Tags: statistical-mechanics, superconductivity

Im confused about the spin of virtual Phonons, my lecture notes suggested that even spin bosons repel opposite charges, and it also suggested that cooper pairs form by considering the "Charge" to be the Spin of the electron. it also stated that the phonon's have spin zero, which would imply that opposite spin should make electrons repel.

My Question; do the virtual phonons that bind cooper pairs have spin '0' and if so, which bit of this have i got wrong?

Thanks, sorry if this is a re-post, i couldn't find anything confirming these points online.